# Finding a value in QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I know that we could find values in a QstandardItem model using `find`. That will return all the items in a specific column that meet a specific citeria. For instance I could do something like this

```
QList<QStandardItem*> lst = Modelname->findItems("SomeString",Qt::MatchExactly,1);
```

Now in the above code column 1 in the model is a string. However I wanted to know if it will be possible to use an expression for a column with doubles. For instance something like this `values >5`

So the statement should perform something like this.

```
 QList<QStandardItem*> lst = Modelname->findItems(>5 ,... , 2); //Column 2 has doubles in it
```

Any suggestion on how I could accomplish that ?

Comment: Just perform the search yourself? It's a normal graph visit...

Answer (score 3):

with `QStandardItemModel::findItems` You can use regular expression `Qt::MatchRegExp`. You cannot do `>5` but you can match text pattern `[^012345]\d*`

However its better to query the backend structure that is feeding data to your model.